# Twilio worker client disconnect reason

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm trying to ensure single worker session/window at a time.

In order to achieve this I have added a [parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#parameters) `closeExistingSessions` to the `createWorker` and it's disconnecting (websocket) the other workerClient as expected.

Just wondering if there is a way to know the disconnect reason using [this disconnected event listener](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#disconnected) so that I can show a relevant message to the end user.

```
const worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(WORKER_TOKEN);

worker.on("disconnected", function(<ANY_ERROR_CODE_OR_SOMETHING_HERE?!>) {
  console.log("Websocket has disconnected");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are getting the `reason` ([The reason the Worker websocket disconnected](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html#event:disconnected)) as parameter to the `disconnected` callback.

```
const worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(WORKER_TOKEN);

worker.on("disconnected", function(reason) {
  console.log(reason.message);
});
```

And the reason for disconnecting due to existing sessions is `'Websocket disconnected due to new connection being registered'`

Hope Twilio will keep their [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#disconnected) up to date